# No class registered error after new instance spin up

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I'm running an app with a Google App Engine server as a backend, using Objectify for datastore interactions. The nature of the app means that there are occasional very sharp spikes in demand. When the spikes happen, GAE spins up new instances.

The problem is that when the spin ups happen, I get a lot of errors for the next few minutes, with the message:

```
Reason: badRequest
Message: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No class 'com.----.-----.-----' was registered
```

Is there a reason for this, and a way to stop it?

Answer (score 1):

Classes which are used at datastore operations, must be registered. If you are using `OfyService`, see below code sample.

```
public class OfyService {

    static {
        ObjectifyService.register(<YourClassHere>.class);
        // TODO: register your classes which are used at datastore operations
    }

    public static Objectify ofy() {
        return ObjectifyService.ofy();
    }

    public static ObjectifyFactory factory() {
        return ObjectifyService.factory();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A stack trace would be more helpful, but you are probably using the datastore before your classes are registered. If you don't have a 100% solid understanding of the order of execution of statics during classloading, your best bet is to register your entity classes in a ServletContextListener.